# react 16 and react router 4, how to test if defined for route component was rendered?

Tags: jestjs, react-router-v4

I have an application based on [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate). I updated it lately to the newest version, which includes react-router 4.2 and also bumped react to version 16.

Now I work on aligning routes in application to the newest version and also want to write tests for routing.

I have main file App.js

```
export default () => (<Switch>
  <Route path="/offer" component={Offer} />
  <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>);
```

And I wrote test:

```
describe('<App />', () => {
  it('should render proper component, based on routing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/offer']} initialIndex={0}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(Offer)).toBePresent();
  });
});
```

I installed [enzyme-matchers](https://github.com/blainekasten/enzyme-matchers) to make `toBePresent` work, but I'm getting an error: `TypeError: expect(...).toBePresent is not a function`.

So probably you know any other way to test with jest if on concrete route defined component was rendered?